# Convert DataTable column values to a lowercase string list after sorting using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataset

I Have a column "OPERATOR_ID" which contain values as 'Condition#10', 'Condition#7', 'Condition#13'etc. I want to retrieve these values from the datatable then sort them based on '#(integer number)' and then convert these string values to lowercase.

I am **able to successfully achieve** it but from performance point I am using lot of memory and It can be done in a better way I feel.

Here is my code:

```
List<object> OPERATOR_ID_Values = new List<object>();

OPERATOR_ID_Values = dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["OPERATOR_ID"]).ToList();
            
var OPERATOR_ID_Values_sort1 = OPERATOR_ID_Values.OrderBy(x => PadNumbers((string)x)).ToList();
            
var OPERATOR_ID_Values_sort = OPERATOR_ID_Values_sort1.Select(x => x.ToString().ToLower()).ToList();
            
public static string PadNumbers(string input)
{
   return Regex.Replace(input, "[0-9]+", match => match.Value.PadLeft(10, '0'));
}
```

"OPERATOR_ID_Values_sort" gives me the desired result.

How Can I make it better from performance point or reduce the LINQ lines. I tried using "ToString().ToLower()" with OrderBy but I dint get the desired result.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head. I'll test and confirm then edit if required:

```cs
var operatorIds = (from row in dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                   let parts = row.Field<string>("OPERATOR_ID").Split('#')
                   order by Convert.ToInt32(parts[1])
                   select $"{parts[0].ToLower()}#{parts[1]}").ToList();
```

Comment: Hello @jmcilhinney ,  I appreciate your effort. If Not the best 1 Linq statement for my solution,  I will also be happy if anything which is better than what currently i am doing.